# Can less than 30 FPS feel good with 60 FPS input handling?

Tags: graphics, performance, input

2D animation can go as low as 12 FPS and still feel good to watch, but the minimum FPS considered to be "playable" in games is 30 fps. I believe this to be a consequence of the user controlling the image in the game and only watching in the movie. But if you where to separate the input handling from the graphics rendering, so that inputs run at 60 FPS and graphics run at 12 FPS, would the game still be "unplayable", or could you get away with that?

Comment: What is the user going to see/know/experience as feedback for their inputs if it is processed more often than the screen redraws? Making a game **feel** playable is all about that feedback. Are you still providing 60 feedbacks per second when you process input at 60 hz? Games can absolutely feel playable below 30 FPS too, you just have to make sure you are not presenting the player with challenges that require very precise timing.

Comment: @Romen I was about to write something fairly similar as an answer below. Would you care to do so, so that I can give you an upvote for it? :)

Comment: I did want to get an answer to my first question before writing a full answer. I'll write it anyway and update if OP's response reveals something interesting to discuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

But it depends on what you do with that input, the player, and the game design as a whole.

#### How a game "feels" is all about feedback.

> I beleive this to be a consequence of the user controlling the image in the game and only watching in the movie.

The critical difference between a movie and a game is that the player gets to interact with the game. The player and the game are connected in a feedback loop. Which is not true for a movie.

[image: Feedback loop between a game and player.]

1. The game presents frames to the player.
2. The player decides what to do based on that feedback.
3. The player provides inputs to the game.
4. The game decides what happens next and renders a new frame.

This loop runs as fast as the slowest step.
So if the player is allowed to send inputs at 60 Hz and the game is only rendering at 30 FPS then your loop repeats at 30 Hz.

So what happens to that input on the un-rendered input "frames"?
If you update the gamestate and just not render another frame then that's actually a completely valid thing to do. I believe that lots of games work this way!
*(I would appreciate if someone could comment a reference for a well known game that has the render loop separated from the input/gamestate loop.)*

However, if there is any kind of visual feedback created by an input then the next frame you render should show that feedback. For example, if you can block an attack and there should be a sprite shown for 1 frame. The player needs to know what happened on the unrendered "frame", otherwise you're completely breaking the feedback loop!

Every input the player makes comes with an expectation that the game will show that their input had an effect.

#### What feels "playable" though?

> 2D animation can go as low as 12 fps and still feel good to watch, but the minimum fps considered to be "playable"in games is 30 fps.

I would start by challenging that statement. Was it an assumption? Who decides what is "playable"?

I believe that limit will be unique to every game and the user themselves factors into the limit.

When this loop runs really fast (like 60 FPS) then the game can become more immersive and also present more difficult timing challenges to the player. Games like first-person shooters benefit from this fast loop because fast moving targets require some quick aim adjustment from the user. If the feedback loop is too slow then you can't accomplish very good aim and the game doesn't feel good.

Meanwhile other games like turn-based strategy, card games, board games, all feel playable at very low framerates. These games do not expect the player to be continuously making inputs, so the player also doesn't expect continuous feedback from the game. The game design allows the framerate to get pretty low before the player would consider it "unplayable".

If you slow down the framerate too much, at some point there will be a noticeable delay on actions like clicking buttons. That can also frustrate a player. (Imagine 1 or 2 FPS)

#### Low Framerate Animation + High Framerate Motion

You should also consider that the rate that an animation plays does not have to be the same thing as the framerate. You can design a sprite sheet with 10 frames to play in a loop at 10 FPS (making 1 second loop), but still render the whole screen at 60 FPS. As the player moves their character around it could play the 10 FPS animation but update their position at 60 FPS.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your comment, I didn't see the notification. You understood exactly what I meant, updating gamestate and not necesseraly rendering it. I asked this question because I'm making an android game and I'm having difficulties putting all the features I want and keep the performances at a reasonnable level.